# Delete from one table where coloumn is not in another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to remove listings from a table where they do not exist in another table.
I am able to select the lists with:

```
SELECT count(mlsnum) as oldRecords
FROM coordinates
WHERE mlsnum NOT IN
(SELECT mlsnum 
 FROM RETS_Listings_full)
```

BUT when I try to delete the listings, I am not able to

```
delete FROM coordinates t1
LEFT JOIN RETS_Listings_full t2 
ON t2.MLSNUM = t1.MLSNUM
WHERE t2.mlsnum IS NULL
```

the error says - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 't1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve a list of `mlsnum` and delete that way

```
DELETE FROM coordinates
WHERE mlsnum IN (
  SELECT mlsnum
  FROM coordinates
  WHERE mlsnum NOT IN (
   SELECT mlsnum
   FROM RETS_Listings_full)
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

> ...where they do not exist...

You are quite near to the solution: use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM coordinates t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM RETS_Listings_full t2 
    WHERE t1.mlsnum = t2.mlsnum 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - clean and simple!

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from mytable where somecommonid not in(select id from myothertable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for your second query

```
DELETE t1
FROM coordinates t1 LEFT JOIN RETS_Listings_full t2 ON t2.MLSNUM = t1.MLSNUM
WHERE t2.mlsnum IS NULL
```